# Jump diffusion -advantages

Tags: finance, risk, brownian-motion, diffusion

What would people say is the advantage of using a Merton jump-diffusion model, in terms of what it models and it's key characteristics/ features?

Comment: This is a bit generic. It would be easier to respond if there is a specific question or point. In general, review papers usually covers such general  considerations:  [Jump-diffusion models: a practitioner’s guide](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.543.6669&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: This would be more on topic on Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange. Consider moving it there.